# Need Advice For PSU For Windows 98 Gaming Build

Tags: power-supply, windows

I have an old Gateway E-3400 that I am upgrading to be my Windows 98 gaming setup, but I'm afraid the stock PSU won't support all the peripherals I want.

It has an NLX motherboard

Link to motherboard specs: https://theretroweb.com/motherboards/s/gvc-mx842

The PC came stock with:
P3 1GHz (100MHz FSB)
3 PCI Slots
Supports 512MB RAM
AGP Slot

The PSU has 4 molex connectors, 1 floppy connector

I've attached a photo of the PSU specs. The stock PSU specs are:

[image: Stock PSU]

145W Maximum Output

+5V - 13A
-5V - 0.3A
+12V - 4.0A
-12V - 0.3A
+3.3 - 14A
+5VSB - 1.7A

Specs of the planned build:

Stock P3 1Ghz ( Uses 29W according to Intel ) ( https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/27529/intel-pentium-iii-processor-1-00-ghz-256k-cache-133-mhz-fsb.html )
Elsa Victory 2 3dfx Voodoo Banshee AGP Card ( Uses 15W ) ( https://www.anandtech.com/show/227 )
512 MB PC133 SDRAM
56K PCI Modem
Adaptec 29160 SCSI PCI Card
Soundblaster Audigy 2 ZS PCI Card ( http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/creative-audigy2-zs/indexOLD.html )
Nakamichi 5 Disc SCSI CD Rom Changer
Iomega 250MB Zip Disk Drive
LS120 Floppy Drive ( Panasonic LKM-F934-1 SuperDisk Drive ) ( https://www.ebay.com › itmPanasonic LKM-F934-1 SuperDisk Drive ... )
Gotek Floppy Emu
PATA/IDE 32GB SSD ( https://a.co/d/j2v4jJ4 )
CF Card W/ CF Card To IDE Adapter ( https://a.co/d/24iXH0h )
Seardrashop HDD Clicker ( https://www.serdashop.com/HDDClicker )

Using the stock PSU I need to split 2 of the molex connectors to plug everything in.

1 Molex would be split into 2 molex adapters to power the HDD Clicker, and the Zip Drive.

Another Molex would be split into 2 floppy power adapters, to power the CF Card Adapter & the Gotek Floppy Emulator.

I'm afraid this PSU won't be sufficient for the planned build. I have most of the parts, but I'm still have a few parts left to pick up.

Looking for some advice on if the stock PSU will be sufficient, or if I need to get a new PSU.

If I need a new PSU it's going to need to be a small form factor, or a PICO PSU, or something similar. Can anyone recommend something that would be a good fit for this planned build?

I've attached a photo of the style of case.

[image: Gateway Case]

I'm not sure how to choose a new PSU, they all seem to be missing some of the negative rails, and I'm not really sure how to choose a PSU that will be sufficient considering I need 5 molex power connectors and 3 floppy style power connectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a [modular SFX power supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BP26PQ1P). They should be small enough and most have several PATA and SATA power connections; whichever you don't use can be adapted to molex.

These SFX power supplies are based on the ATX standard instead of the older AT standard, so they do not have the -5V rail. However, I believe that only the original IBM actually used that rail and only for peripherals. It is not needed by the processor.